# Android library string overrides project string

Tags: android

Have the following problem:
got the `<string name="amount">Amount</string>` in my strings
also got `<string name="amount">%1$.2f USD</string>` in aar library strings (library is a must to use, I cannot not to use it)
and in project library string value somehow overrides my project string value, as I got from android developer site it shouldn't be so, appreciate any advices/help

Comment: How are you using it ? in code most probably the import is wrong so R.string is imported from the lib.

Comment: @PedroAGSantos, it is happening with     android:hint="@string/amount_" in xml fie of layout